# Why isn't my python shell indenting automatically?

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been given a question:

Write a piece of Python code that prints out one of the following messages:

"string involved" if either VarA or VarB are strings

"bigger" if VarA is larger than VarB

"equal" if VarA is equal to VarB

"smaller" if VarA is smaller than VarB

---

Here's my solution:

```
if type(varA) == str or type(varB) == str:
    print("string involved")
elif varA>varB:
    print("bigger")
elif varA==varB:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("smaller")
```

This looks exactly the same as the given answer, but it is incorrect, and I think it has something to do with my indentation. For some reason, after the `if` statement on the first line, the shell doesn't automatically indent the next line automatically. Why is this? I had to press TAB after each line that followed an `if` or `elif` statement. Also, what exactly is wrong with the code that I've written?

Edit: The correct answer is:

```
if type(varA) == str or type(varB) == str:
    print('string involved')
elif varA > varB:
    print('bigger')
elif varA == varB:
    print('equal')
else:
    # If none of the above conditions are true,
    # it must be the case that varA < varB
    print('smaller')
```

Not only do I want to know where I've gone wrong (everything seems correct), but I'd also like to know why the Spyder shell is not automatically indenting lines beginning with `elif` or `else`.

Comment: Why is it wrong, whats expected output and whats your output also your vars in line 1 start with V while the others start with v.  Wrt the shell, what are you using to write the python?

Comment: Also, what shell?

Comment: @NickA I'm using Spyder.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated the info to be clearer. What exactly is going on? Why is the Spyder shell not automatically indenting?

Comment: You're asking two questions, which isn't useful. If you want to know about spyder, look into the config and consider raising a bug if there isn't one already.